# Can rebol trim remove blank lines without removing CRLF?

Tags: rebol

I wanted to use trim to remove blank lines:

```
line 1

line 2
```

to get

```
line1
line2
```

but using

```
trim/lines
```

does also remove CRLF. So is there another way to use trim for that purpose ?

Comment: Your mention of CRLF is unclear as you also use "blank lines" expression. Rebol does not use CRLF sequence to mark a new line, but LF character. So do you mean LF, or do you mean a Rebol string which contain CRLF sequences (ASCII 13 followed by ASCII 10)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
replace/all {Line1^/^/Line2} {^/^/} {^/}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `PARSE`:

```
parse string-with-newlines [
    any [
          crlf remove some crlf
        | newline remove some newline
        | skip
    ]
]
```

It may be faster to use charsets though:

```
text: complement charset crlf
parse string-with-newlines [
    any [
          some text
        | crlf any crlf
        | newline remove any newline
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

No way just with trim, but here a solution with removeach and also, also removing leading LFs

```
trim-emptyline: func [
    str [string!] 
    /local lfb4 lfnow c
] [
    lfb4: true 
    remove-each c str [also all [lfnow: lf = c lfb4] lfb4: lfnow]
    str
]
```